# block of worlds with position aware goal stack planning

Tags: ai-design, path-planning

Can someone suggest an AI approach to moving blocks, one at a time, assuming control of an robotic arm, to get from the initial state on the left to the final state on right, preferably using goal stack planning.

**actions**

- Pickup() — to pick up a block from table only
- Putdown — to putdown a block on table only
- Unstack — unstack a block from another block
- Stack — stack a block on another clear block only

**property functions**

- On(x,y)
- Above(x,y)
- Table(x)
- Clear(x)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to formulate the problem in [PDDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Domain_Definition_Language), which should be fairly easy, and then use a standard planner to generate a plan from that description.

In PDDL you describe the properties and the possible actions, the start state and the goal state, and the planner will then take this to produce a sequence of actions that leads from the start state to the goal state. There is a [planner available on-line](http://editor.planning.domains/) that you can use.